# How can i load song album art to an ImageView with Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso, albumart

```
public void getSongs() {

    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);


    if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int data_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int title_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artist_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int album_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        do {

            Long songId = myCursor.getLong(id_Column);
            String songData = myCursor.getString(data_Column);
            String songName = myCursor.getString(title_Column);
            String songArtist = myCursor.getString(artist_Column);
            String songAlbum  = myCursor.getString(album_Column);

            long parseLong = Long.parseLong(songAlbum);
            final Uri sArtWorkUri =  Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtWorkUri, parseLong);

            Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(albumArt);

            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(songId, songData, songName, songArtist);
            songList.add(querySongs);

        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
        myCursor.close();
    }
}
```

How can i load album covers to an imageView? In my method getSongs i tried it with Picasso, but doesn't load the art.

How can i solve this?

Thanks,
-Vince

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(albumArt); i know im missing something here but i don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file object from the Uri as below:

```
...

long parseLong = Long.parseLong(songAlbum);
        final Uri sArtWorkUri =  
Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtWorkUri, parseLong);

File file = new File(uri.getPath());
Picasso.with(getContext())
        .load(file)  
        .error(R.drawable.mountain) 
        .into(albumArt);
```

Comment: File file = new File(uri);
here is an error which says "cannot resolve constructor 'File(android.net.Uri)'

Comment: you need to do this: `File file = new File(uri.getPath());`  , I'll edit the answer

Comment: Ok, now it's not crashing anymore, but i doesn't show the album covers, only the art when there is no album cover.

Comment: I want to get the album covers from the songs i read from my sdcard.

Comment: Grab a URI reference to the cover and apply the same logic.

Comment: And on other posts i see people working with bitmap?

Comment: Still doesn't work, can you show in code how to do it?